Importing plotly.express gives attribution error
I am trying to import plotly.express for a project but python is throwing me an error:
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'float'.
`np.float` was a deprecated alias for the builtin `float`. 
To avoid this error in existing code, use `float` by itself. 
Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. 
If you specifically wanted the numpy scalar type, use `np.float64` here.

I have plotly.express version 0.4.1, plotly version 5.22.0 and the latest version of numpy. How do I use plotly.express without downgrading numpy?

If you can, edit the question to include the complete traceback (i.e. the complete error message) in the question.  That should show which line produces the error. It might be occurring in a dependency of plotly.
